# I have to pair bluetooth headset each time to get good sound quality

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headset, Sony MDR-1000x, that works correctly on any other device. But on my laptop, a Dell XPS 15 9570, I have a sound quality problem.

If I simply connect my headset by powering on my headset and click on the bluetooth menu on my computer, I will get a crappy sound quality. The sound will be distorded, it sounds more metallic and lower than it should. But if I put it in pairing mode and then connect my laptop to it, the sound quality is fine.

What can I do so that my laptop works correctly ?

Here is some information that could be useful.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.15.0-48-generic
Shell: Bash 4.4.19
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug and file a bug against pulseaudio